# WSO2 VFS transport parses text files

Tags: wso2, esb, vfs

I am quite new to WSO2 and I need to validate if the product can suit our needs. I have an FTP server with lots of .csv files and they might even contain binary files. What I want to do is get the messages with WSO2 ESB VFS to a RabbitMQ and a consumer there picks it of the queue. This is working fine already, but if I put files with kinda 'unexpected format', this file is dropped by WSO2. But I do not want WSO2 to examine or judge my files, my application on the MQ consumer end is taking care of that. How can I instruct my VFS transport to ignore the file structure and just move it on?

Comment: What's the content type you use? and what message builder/formatters do you use? Do you see any errors in ESB logs?

Comment: I altered the message builders/formatters, basically added application/zip and application/binary, and that seemed to have solved something. Is there any limit on the 'message' itself?

Comment: The content of the file will be attempted to parse based on the content type used. I suggest you use text/plain for the content type.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, done by setting message builders and formaters.